# Which Magento tables are affected by deleting customers via the admin area

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

A client of mine on Magento (ver. 1.7.0.2) deleted all customers by way of the admin area.

We have a recent DB backup to recover the data from, which tables need to be recovered to resume normal operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the required tables to recover lost customers.

- customer_address_entity
- customer_address_entity_datetime
- customer_address_entity_decimal
- customer_address_entity_int
- customer_address_entity_text
- customer_address_entity_varchar
- customer_eav_attribute
- customer_eav_attribute_website
- customer_entity
- customer_entity_datetime
- customer_entity_decimal
- customer_entity_int
- customer_entity_text customer_entity_varchar

If replacing the tables is not an option (more customers have signed up), Mysql REPLACE can be used in lieu of INSERT (to prevent duplicate key errors).